# Insert new line below in VScode with Jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, line

How to insert a new line below in a cell with "shift+enter" in VScode with Jupyter!

I try to edit key bindings but it does not make any change!

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UBWu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it,
"keybindings.json" file

```json
[
    {
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "command": "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "-editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "python.execInTerminal"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "command": "-notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow",
        "when": "notebookCellListFocused && notebookCellType == 'markdown' || notebookCellListFocused && notebookCellExecutionState == 'failed' || notebookCellExecutionState == 'idle' || notebookCellExecutionState == 'succeeded' && notebookKernelCount > 0"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "notebook.cell.execute",
        "when": "notebookCellListFocused && notebookCellType == 'code' && notebookCellExecutionState == 'failed' || notebookCellExecutionState == 'idle' || notebookCellExecutionState == 'succeeded' && notebookKernelCount > 0"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+enter",
        "command": "-notebook.cell.execute",
        "when": "notebookCellListFocused && notebookCellType == 'code' && notebookCellExecutionState == 'failed' || notebookCellExecutionState == 'idle' || notebookCellExecutionState == 'succeeded' && notebookKernelCount > 0"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Shift+Enter" is mapped to `notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow` by default in VS Code notebooks. You may need to edit the keybindings for `notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow` and any other commands currently associated with "Shift+Enter" first.

Comment: ok, I edited the keybindings for notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow but nothing changed, so what can I do next?

Answer (score 0):

The default keybinding for "Insert a new line below" in the Editor is "ctrl+enter", which is assigned to the command "editor.action.insertLineAfter" by default. However, I couldn’t find any equivalent command in Notebook that can be assigned to "shift+enter", as you desired.

Therefore, I suggest using "ctrl+enter" in Notebook as well. This will also prevent the conflicts that @joceerhl mentioned before.

To do this, you will need to remove (or assign different key combination to) the default mapping for "ctrl+enter" in Notebook. This will allow the default "ctrl+enter" command for the editor to work in Notebook as well.

Here are the steps to do so:

1. Open: "File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts";
2. Search for "Notebook: Execute Cell and Focus Container";
3. Doble-click to assign a different key combination to this command.

Alternatively, you can add the following code to your "keybindings.json" file:

```
{
    "key": "your_key_combination_here",
    "command": "notebook.cell.executeAndFocusContainer",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused || editorTextFocus && inputFocus && notebookEditorFocused"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "-notebook.cell.executeAndFocusContainer",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused || editorTextFocus && inputFocus && notebookEditorFocused"
},
```

Replace "your_key_combination_here" in the first line with the desired key combination. Make sure to save the "keybindings.json" file after making the changes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write detailed instructions, Actually I got it solved a while ago, and I will post the fix that worked for me